# Solving for the average values of cells using openpyxl

Tags: python

How can i obtained the average of the values from B2:B1500 as shown in the code below.

```
wb=xl.load_workbook("J:/Data/T0444CH1.xlsx")
    type(wb)
    ws = wb.active
    tuple(ws['B2':'B1500'])
    cells=[]
    for rowOfCellObjects in ws['B2':'B1500']:
        for cellObj in rowOfCellObjects:
            cells.append(cellObj)
    av = sum(cells)/len(cells)
```

This is the error i am getting

```
av = sum(cells)/len(cells)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Cell'
```

Comment: Are you using any special libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you are adding the Cell Objects with an integer, so in this case, we need to get the cell's value. So, one way to get the value is to extract it from the object itself with `cellObj.value`.

By modifying your code, we can do this, namely by appending the value instead of the cell object itself.

```
wb=xl.load_workbook("J:/Data/T0444CH1.xlsx")
type(wb)
ws = wb.active
tuple(ws['B2':'B1500'])
cells=[]
for rowOfCellObjects in ws['B2':'B1500']:
    for cellObj in rowOfCellObjects:
        cells.append(cellObj.value)
av = sum(cells)/len(cells)
```

Note: Again, I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

The list cells is basically appending the values in the column, in a string format. this is the reason why you are getting that error.

To solve this error, you need to first map the values into int or float and then continue calculating the average.

Do -

```
cells = list(map(float, cells))
```

and then calculate average!